# ARKit: Issues with Anchors and Planes Movement or Removal upon Background-Foreground Transition

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm encountering unexpected behavior in my ARKit application when transitioning between the background and foreground states. Specifically, I'm observing that the anchor is either moving or, in some cases, both the anchor and associated plane are removed.

I have implemented methods to pause and resume the ARKit session appropriately during these transitions. However, the issue persists. I've also handled interruptions and session state changes but haven't found a solution yet.

Here are the key aspects of my implementation:

Applied Solution 1 :

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    // Run the view's session
     arViewModel.arView.session.run(configuration)
}

 func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    // Pause the view's session
     arViewModel.arView.session.pause()
}
```

And

Applied Solution 2 :

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
     arView.session.pause()
 }

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
       // Run the view's session
      arViewModel.arView.session.run(configuration)
 }
```

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I'm looking for insights or additional strategies to ensure the stability of anchors and planes when the app transitions between the background and foreground states.

Any suggestions, code snippets, or experiences with similar scenarios would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!